# At what stage is a tensorflow graph set up?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

An optimizer typically run the same computation graph for many steps until convergence. Does tensorflow setup the graph at the beginning and reuse it for every step? What if I change the batch size during training? What if I make some minus change to the graph like changing the loss function? What if I made some major change to the graph? Does tensorflow pre-generate all possible graphs? Does tensorflow know how to optimize the entire computation when the graph changes?

Answer (score 8):

As [keveman says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35492929/3574081), from the client's perspective there is a single TensorFlow graph. In the runtime, there can be multiple *pruned* subgraphs that contain just the nodes that are necessary to compute the values `t1`, `t2` etc. that you fetch when calling [`sess.run([t1, t2, ...])`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run).

If you call `sess.run([t1, t2])` will prune the overall graph (`sess.graph`) down to the subgraph required to compute those values: i.e. the operations that produce `t1` and `t2` and all of their antecedents. If you subsequently call `sess.run([t3, t4])`, the runtime will prune the graph down to the subgraph required to compute `t3` and `t4`. Each time you pass a new combination of values to fetch, TensorFlow will compute a new pruned graph and cache it—this is why the first `sess.run()` can be somewhat slower than subsequent ones.

If the pruned graphs overlap, TensorFlow will reuse the "kernel" for the ops that are shared. This is relevant because some ops (e.g. [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) and [`tf.FIFOQueue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#FIFOQueue)) are *stateful*, and their contents can be used in both pruned graphs. This allows you, for example, to initialize your variables with one subgraph (e.g. `sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())`), train them with another (e.g. `sess.run(train_op)`), and evaluate your model with a third (e.g. `sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: ...})`). It also lets you enqueue elements to a queue with one subgraph, and dequeue them with another, which is the foundation of the [input pipelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html).

Comment: It is important to note that the pruning does not include the pruning of the inactive branches of a `tf.cond` node. The inputs to both `fn1` and `fn2` remain in the graph and are computed. Only the nodes defined *within* the `fn1` and `fn2` functions are computed conditionally.

Answer (score 6):

TensorFlow exposes only one graph that is visible to the user, namely the one specified by the user. The user can run the graph with [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) or by calling [`Tensor.eval()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor.eval) on some tensor. A `Session.run()` call can specify some tensors to be fed and others to be fetched. Depending on what needs to be fetched, the TensorFlow runtime could be internally constructing and optimizing various data structures, including a pruned version of the user visible graph. However, this internal graph is not visible to the user in anyway. No, TensorFlow doesn't 'pre-generate' all possible graphs. Yes, TensorFlow does perform extensive optimizations on the computation graph. And finally, changing the batch size of a tensor that is fed doesn't change the structure of the graph.

Comment: @mrry Thanks. I still don't quite get what happens if Session.run( ) are called twice on different tensors/ops, which may need different computation graphs. (In a typical optimization problems, Session.run() are repeatedly called to execute the same op, but the op can change in principle.)

Comment: I added an answer that addresses your follow-up question. Let me know if it makes things clear!

Comment: @mrry Got it. Clear now. Thanks a lot!