# why do tensorflow compute Sigmoid's output again when compute the gradient of Sigmod?

Tags: tensorflow

Reading the source code of the tensorflow I found the Sigmoid Gradient Computation is defined below.

```
Status SigmoidGrad(const AttrSlice& attrs, FunctionDef* g) {
// clang-format off
return GradForUnaryCwise(g, {
  {{"y"}, "Sigmoid", {"x"}},
  FDH::Const("const", 1.0f),
  {{"one"}, "Cast", {"const"}, {{"SrcT", DT_FLOAT}, {"DstT", "$T"}}},
  {{"a"}, "Sub", {"one", "y"}, {}, {"dy"}},
  {{"b"}, "Mul", {"y", "a"}},             // y * (1 - y)
  {{"dx"}, "Mul", {"dy", "b"}},           // dy * y * (1 - y)
});
// clang-format on
}
```

My question is, why do tensorflow recompute the Sigmoid's output for computing it's gradient. Isn't it stored in the op's context??

The code piece comes from [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cf18c6d384a96a53b448bd51a90c117af0ed7c96/tensorflow/core/ops/math_grad.cc#L228)

Answer (score 1):

Derivative of sigmoid can be calculated in terms of sigmoid:

[image]

So TF can reuse some of its previous notes to calculate the result.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do tensorflow recompute the Sigmoid's output for its gradient?

It does not — that's the beauty of frameworks such as tensorflow. [Tensorflow will reuse nodes that can be reused.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491633/at-what-stage-is-a-tensorflow-graph-set-up/35518402#35518402) So the sigmoid node in the gradient will automagically reuse the sigmoid computation.

Note that node reuse is much more powerful than a per-op optimization, because the optimization can happen anywhere in the graph, between different operations.

Comment: Did you mean that we just define a new node at building graph stage, and when we call sess.run(), tensorflow will optimize it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is done dynamically before evaluation.

Comment: Thanks.  I have one more question, why do we define a node  `{"y"}, "Sigmoid", {"x"}` instead of directly  use context->output to get the sigmoid's output in FDH?

Comment: I am not sure. I would say if both are equivalent, then the former is more consistent. Also the later leaves the impression that this is an optimization, and therefore something one should do, which would be counterproductive.