# Does TensorFlow recompute nodes even if there are exactly the same computations already defined elsewhere in the graph?

Tags: tensorflow

Consider for example this example:

```
train_op = opt.minimize(loss)
gradients = tf.gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())
```

Are the gradients computed twice or just once?

Or this example:

```
a = y + z
b = y + z
```

Is the addition `y + z` computed twice or just once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is computed only once. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35518402/1735003) for more info about this and other optimizations tensorflow does at runtime.